# How are unicode values encoded in Google Cloud Load Balancer custom headers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, geolocation, load-balancing

When using Google Cloud Load Balancer, you can add certain fields to custom headers such as `{client_city}`, which (surely?) are unicode strings.

I cannot find in the documentation how these are encoded in the header (bearing in mind that HTTP headers are ASCII only, or possibly Latin-1 according the "obsolete" productions in the HTTP RFC).

Since I'm in a city with an ASCII name, I've not been able to run a test from my local box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a document for this:

> client_city:
>
> Name of the city from which the request originated, for
>   example, “Mountain View” for Mountain View, California. There is no
>   canonical list of valid values for this variable. The city names may
>   contain US-ASCII letters, numbers, spaces, and the following
>   characters: `` !#$%&'*+-.^_`|~ ``.

Some headers can be Unicode, whereas some well known headers are Ascii.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service

Comment: I'm a bozo, thank you!

(Regarding unicode in headers: according to RFC7230, header values must be VCHAR (visible ASCII only), or the obsolete obs-text (Latin-1), so if other Unicode text needs to be transported the header has to define some header-specific escaping mechanism for transporting the value using ASCII.